# SO as a blog platform

Tags: discussion, blog

Without a doubt there are a lot of smart StackOverflow users who would like to share or discuss something inside SO community without masking it as a question. So are there any plans to create blogs.stackoverflow.com based on StackExchange engine? To make it more interesting we can set some registration barrier (for example 1000 reputation + yearling badge) which can be also a good motivator to gain some reputation.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to post one-way content (not Q&A) and have everyone be able to do it, or just a select few as @jmort253 suggests?  My +1 is for the former.

Comment: Definitely that would be great to have a blog and to be able to post and repost some questions with moderation and ability to comment on each other blogs.

Please consider this feature as developers really like blogging on other platforms, why not to blog @ SO

Answer (score 3):

This is already an active discussion, and there are already ideas on the table to create other blogs.

http://blog.superuser.com is now official, and is run entirely by the community and the community elected moderators.

[The Super User Blog -- now officially blessed!](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2153/the-super-user-blog-now-officially-blessed/2158#2158)

There is also talk of a blog for [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).  Additionally, [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) has a blog at http://blog.serverfault.com, but it appears to be run by StackExchange employees instead of the community.

If you're interested, bring up the topic on your per-site Meta.  See how many people are interested in the subject.  Keep in mind that you'll need enough people who can keep the blog updated once per week in order for it to hold value, and it will also have to be unique and not just another run-of-the-mill blog.